# Why does installing collectd on Ubuntu 16.04 require X11?

Tags: apt, software-installation, xorg, monitoring

I am setting up monitoring using Riemann and collectd on my server.
When I do `sudo apt-get install collectd` , I get a huge list of packages including X11, fonts and icon-themes.

The other option is to install `collectd-core` but the package description says that it does not come with default configs. What am I missing out on if I install `collectd-core` instead of `collectd` ? I do not want to install X11 libraries on my server.

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends`?

Comment: @muru Even that lists lib-x11* libraries as dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the packages here http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/collectd.
Keep in mind, that `--no-install-recommends` applies recursively to all dependencies, so I would try something like:

```
sudo apt-get install collectd-core #to make sure recommendations will be installed too and then

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends collectd
```

If you follow the dependencies there is for example the chain `librrd4`-> `libcairo2`-> `libx11-6` which can't be avoided when you install `collectd` since it's dependency and not recommendation, but it's just libraries so I don't know why you don't want them installed. In order to avoid it, install only the package `collectd-core` and then with the option `--no-install-recommends` additional packages that you might need (you need to figure them out yourself).